# How to load balance Cassandra cluster nodes?

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra-0.7.8 on cluster of 4 machines. I have uploaded some files using Map/Reduce.
It looks files got distributed only among 2 nodes. When I used RF=3 it had got distributed to equally 4 nodes on below configurations.

Here are some config info's:

1. ByteOrderedPartitioner
2. Replication Factor = 1 (since, I have storage problem. It will be increased later )
3. initial token - value has not been set.
4. create keyspace ipinfo with replication_factor = 1 and placement_strategy = 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy';

> [cassandra@cassandra01 apache-cassandra-0.7.8]$ bin/nodetool -h
>   172.27.10.131 ring Address         Status State   Load            Owns    Token
>                                                          **Token(bytes[fddfd9bae90f0836cd9bff20b27e3c04])
>   172.27.10.132   Up     Normal  11.92 GB        25.00%  Token(bytes[3ddfd9bae90f0836cd9bff20b27e3c04])
>   172.27.15.80    Up     Normal  10.21 GB        25.00%**  Token(bytes[7ddfd9bae90f0836cd9bff20b27e3c04])
>   172.27.10.131   Up     Normal  54.34 KB        25.00%  Token(bytes[bddfd9bae90f0836cd9bff20b27e3c04])
>   172.27.15.78    Up     Normal  58.79 KB        25.00%  Token(bytes[fddfd9bae90f0836cd9bff20b27e3c04])

Can you suggest me how can I balance the load on my cluster.

Regards,
Thamizhannal

Answer (score 2):

The keys in the data you loaded did not get high enough to reach the higher 2 nodes in the ring.  You could change to the RandomPartitioner as suggested by frail.  Another option would be to rebalance your ring as described in the [Cassandra wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/Operations#Load_balancing).  This is the route you will want to take if you want to continue having your keys ordered.  Of course as more data is loaded, you'll want to rebalance again to keep the distribution of data relatively even.  If you plan on doing just random reads and no range slices then switch to the RandomPartitioner and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want better loadbalance you need to change your partitioner to RandomPartitioner. But it would cause problems if you are using range queries in your application. You would better check this article :

[Cassandra: RandomPartitioner vs OrderPreservingPartitioner](http://ria101.wordpress.com/2010/02/22/cassandra-randompartitioner-vs-orderpreservingpartitioner/)

Comment: Since I wanted to have "Rowkey" in sorted order I sticked to "ByteOrderedPartitioner". 
ten.tenih28082700
ten.tenih28229682

Comment: Since I wanted to have Row-key in sorted order I sticked to ByteOrderedPartitioner.Here are some of my row keys.
16850236
18237452
18247843
.......
ten.tenih28082700
ten.tenih28229682
.............
ua.moc.tensutpo19525884
ua.moc.tensutpo19535056
ua.moc.tensutpo19726324

I guess these could have created some hot spot.Here the row keys, start from "number" and ends at "ua.... ". So It could have been eventually distributed to other nodes as well. Why it is not?

I am bit confussing about "ByteOrderedPartitioner" Vs "OrderPreservingPartitioner". Can you name out some use case for this?.

Comment: I assumed you have "active" dataset, not passive one. That's why my answer was pointing out the "time-series" problem in big datasets. If your data is basicly "passive" data (no more insert coming in) you can arrange your nodes so that data evenly distributed. But when more data comes it would go to one node only, so your load-balancing would be useless.

Comment: OrderPreservingPartitioner is obsolete, it has been replaced by ByteOrderedPartitioner which is more general.